# Fade in/out text based upon value of counter

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:-

```
<textarea id="TextBox1"></textarea>
<span id="validator"></span>
```

And the following jQuery:-

```
jQuery('#TextBox1').live('input', function() {
    var charLength = $(this).val().length;
    $('#validator').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');
    if ($(this).val().length > 250) {
        $('#validator').html('<strong>You may only have up to 250 characters !</strong>');
    } 
});
```

This works fine.

I wish to modify the above jQuery so that the `#validator` fades in when it appears and also fades out if the length drops to 0 (doesn't do this currently, message stays on the screen).

**EDIT:** Forgot to add, I have the following function also:-

```
jQuery.fn.fadeInOrOut = function(status) {
    return status ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();
};
```

I have tried the following but it doesent seem to have any effect:-

```
$('#validator').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used').fadeInOrOut(!! charLength);
```

and...

```
$('#validator').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');
$('#validator').fadeInOrOut(!! charLength);
```

Comment: could you setup a fiddle we can play with? :)

Comment: @NiftyDude sure, http://jsfiddle.net/general_exception/CsXU8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/CsXU8/3/

You need to hide the validator onload (with css). else it cannot fade in.

So adding this line in your css:

```
#validator {display:none}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This works great thanks. However in IE the counter wont reduce. Have a look at the fiddle in IE.

Answer (score 0):

set the style of `#validator` to `display:none`
and then use this

```
jQuery('#TextBox1').live('input', function() {
    var charLength = $(this).val().length;
    $('#validator').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');    
    if ($(this).val().length > 250) {
        $('#validator').html('<strong>You may only have up to 250 characters !</strong>');
    }
    $('#validator').fadeIn(200);
    if(charLength == 0)
    $('#validator').fadeOut(200); 
});
```