# jQuery .live('input) in IE not working when removing text

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Based on this question [Fade in/out text based upon value of counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780756/fade-in-out-text-based-upon-value-of-counter)

I have the following markup:-

```
<textarea id="TextBox1"></textarea>
<br/>
<span id="validator" style="display:none"></span>
```

and the following jQuery:-

```
jQuery('#TextBox1').live('input', function() {

    var charLength = $(this).val().length;

    $('#validator').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');
    $('#validator').fadeInOrOut(!! charLength);

    if ($(this).val().length > 250) {
        $('#validator').html('<strong>You may only have up to 250 characters !</strong>');
    }

});

jQuery.fn.fadeInOrOut = function(status) {
    return status ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();
};
```

This all works fine in Firefox, but in IE, specifically when removing text from the textarea the .live() event doesn't seem to get fired.

There is a fiddle here that demonstrates the above, if you load in Firefox functionality works fine, load in IE and add some text to the textarea, then remove some text using the backspace key.

http://jsfiddle.net/general_exception/CsXU8/

**EDIT** using `on` doesent seem to make a difference, the bug still remains.

Comment: The `input` event isn't widely supported.

Comment: `live` is deprecated in 1.7 in favor of `on`, please use `on` instead :(

Comment: How would I modify the above to have the same functionality working in IE ??

Comment: fastest would be `.live('keyup', function() { ... })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of jQuery, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .live(), and instead of binding to `input`, just use `keyup` to catch the event

```
jQuery('#TextBox1').on('keyup', function() { });
```

Comment: There is, but there's no need to do it - you'd be complicating your code for absolutely no benefit whatsoever. I'd just avoid the `input` event.

Comment: While I agree with Christian you can use `jQuery.browser` for browser detection. i.e; `if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead of `input` which is not generally supported. Also you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of deprecated `live`:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#TextBox1', function() {
    ...
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CsXU8/10/

Answer (score 0):

For IE8/9, replace first line using  following code

`jQuery('#TextBox1').on('keyup', function() {`